# Why doesn't default props work in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am training how to use default props and I ran into a problem. Can anyone explain to me why default props doesn't work in this case?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import defaultImage from '../../../assets/DefaultImageOnError.svg'

export const ImageComponent = ({ props }) => {
    return (
        <img width={ props.size } src={ props.src } alt={ props.alt }/>
    );
};

ImageComponent.propTypes = {
    props: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string),
};

ImageComponent.defaultProps = {
    props: {
        size: '150px',
        src: defaultImage,
        alt: 'error'
    }
}
```

When I turn off props for this component in another file. The component should load defaultprops. Why is this not happening?

Comment: Could you expand on the problem? One thing that seems a little odd is to have a prop named `props`.

Comment: When I turn off props for this component in another file. The component should load defaultprops. Why is this not happening?

Comment: And what does "turn off props" mean? Give a [mre].

Comment: Props is an object, when you do { props } you are accessing props.props instead of props.

Comment: It looks like your issue is that you are expecting a single prop named `props` but you're _using_ the component as if all the props are top-level.  Either remove the `{}` around your `props` in `ImageComponent = ({ props }) => {` or update your default props to be `props: { props: {default: "values"} }`

Comment: We assumed that having a prop named `props` was a typo. Please refer to the documentation on [typechecking with prop types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and if you really wanted `props` to be a prop, please update your question to show how the `ImageComponent` is used and ask to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2):

Props is an object, when you do { props } you are accessing props.props instead of props.

Just replace

```
export const ImageComponent = ({ props }) => {
```

and

```
ImageComponent.defaultProps = {
    props: {
        size: '150px',
        src: defaultImage,
        alt: 'error'
    }
}
```

With

```
export const ImageComponent = (props) => {
    const {size, src, alt} = props;
```

or

```
export const ImageComponent = ({size, src, alt}) => {
    ...
```

And update propTypes to match (this is probably a typo in your exmaple):

```
ImageComponent.defaultProps = {
    size: '150px',
    src: defaultImage,
    alt: 'error'
}
```

To simplify this, and prevent these kinds of mistakes in the future, consider using object destructuring to set defaults instead:

```
export const ImageComponent = (props) => {
    const {
        size = '150px', 
        src = defaultImage, 
        alt = 'error',
    } = props;
```

or

```
export const ImageComponent = ({
  size = '150px', 
  src = defaultImage, 
  alt = 'error',
}) => {
    ...
```

Comment: It's unusual and perhaps confusing, but they are consistent in referring to a prop named props. If they made the change you suggest they'd need to make others too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and they should adjust their proptypes and default props to be consistent otherwise, default props won't be applied properly.

Comment: @EmileBergeron exactly, but that's not shown in this answer. At least what the OP started with was internally consistent.